# why does this "while(cin.get(str,3))" only run once whatever you put in?

Tags: c++

what happened in `while()`?
Does input stream have EOF in the end?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        char str[10];
        while(cin.get(str,10))
          cout<<str<<endl;//only run once,why
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I9hEp4o7bri89WPE)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? And it seems to be working fine here...

Comment: EOF should not break the loop, only an error bit.

Answer (score 2):

The `istream::get` overload you're calling reads until a newline (`\n`), but does not read the newline itself.

The next time around it encounters the newline and can't read anything, setting the `failbit`, that causes `operator bool ()` to return `false` and the loop exits.

Use `cin.getline` instead.